# Energy efficient CRT, LCD, LED?

Tags: display, lcd, led, crt

Not intended for subjective or argumentative replies but i wanted to know in order to save some electricity bills which monitor is going to be best bet.

LED monitors are currently not available in my town so there is no chance i can get them for next 6 months atleast.But still want to know about their features and if they're better for eyes and energy saving. Between CRT and LCD which is more energy saver ? Which is more better for eyes ? LED,LCD or CRT ?

Comment: Nanoemitters. But 6 months is nothing compared to them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LCD all the way.

LED monitors are not yet out, and what you hear about "LED monitors" is just marketing for LED backlit LCD monitors.

Comment: The LED backlight still draws a lot less power than fluorescent though.

Comment: Valid point @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams , but is it noticeable ?

Comment: Agreed, LCDs pull far less power than a CRT. They also use a lot less power on standby (on standby, CRTs keep the coils warmed up), and their energy usage doesn't change based on what image is being displayed, it's constant. An LCD is much better for your eyes as it doesn't flicker like a CRT does. tl;dr LED > LCD > CRT

Comment: n.b.: The coils don't have to "warm up". The deflection coils, if that's what you're thinking of, are most certainly _not_ powered when a CRT is in standby, nor do they have to be for a quick wake-up. Besides the signal input circuits and microprocessor (enough to tell when it's time to wake up), the only thing you might want to keep "warm" is the CRT filament, and its power use is very small, maybe five watts at most. Even that could be turned off after a lengthy standby period.